# Java execute command line program 'find' returns error

Tags: java, bash, find

The following works from the terminal no problem

```
find testDir -type f -exec md5sum {} \;
```

Where `testDir` is a directory that contains some files (for example file1, file2 and file3).

However, I get an error using the following in Java

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec("find testDir -type f -exec md5sum {} \\;");
```

The error is

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I believe I am escaping the characters correctly. I have tried several different formats and I cannot get this to work.

**UPDATE** @jtahlborn answered the question perfectly. But the command has now changed slightly to sort each file in the dir before calculating the md5sum and is as follows (I have already accepted the excellent answer for the original question so I'll buy somebody a beer if they can come up with the format for this. I have tried every combination I can think of following the answer below with no success.)

> "find testDir -type f -exec md5sum {} + | awk {print $1} | sort |
>   md5sum ;"

**NEW UPDATE**

For pipe, you need a shell so I ended up with this, which works great and you can still get the output.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(new String[] 
{
    "sh", "-l", "-c", "find " + directory.getPath() + " -type f -exec md5sum {} + | awk '{print $1}' | sort | md5sum"
});
```

Comment: How do you get the feedback? A [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org) would be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the multi-argument call to exec (otherwise you can get bitten by escape rules).  also, since you aren't calling from a shell script, you don't need to escape the semicolon:

```
Process pr = rt.exec(new String[]{"find", "testDir", "-type", "f", "-exec", "md5sum", "{}", ";"});
```

Comment: Brilliant. I tried this earlier but had the whole exec params as one string - "-exec", "md5sum {} ;"

Comment: or Runtime.getRuntime().exec("find testDir -type f -exec md5sum {} \\;".split(" "));

Comment: Okay I will buy you a beer if you can format this "find testDir -type f -exec md5sum {} + | awk {print $1} | sort | md5sum ;"

Answer (score 0):

For things like pipe, you need a shell which you don't get with Runtime.exec.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(new String[] 
{
    "sh", "-l", "-c", "find " + directory.getPath() + " -type f -exec md5sum {} + | awk '{print $1}' | sort | md5sum"
});
```